# how to call a tapGesture IBAction from code in obiective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, event-handling, action, uitapgesturerecognizer

i have a view and i add tapGesture with a handle function to this view,
and i want to call the tap action from code,for calling the handle function ....

**-(IBAction) handleTapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender**

how can i do that???

now i can get this view, how to call the tap action from code?

i find some function about it,but it doesnot work well .

like the :   *UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents / UIView performSelector ...*

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
[theView handleTapGesture:nil];
```

?

Answer (score 0):

IN your view controller,put this code

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [self.currentImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];

 then write your code for tap function in

-(void) handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

}
```